# How to combine data from two independent tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

How to combine data from two independent tables?

I have:

```
car:
id | name | date                | info_id
1  | Audi | 2018-08-30 08:10:10 | null
2  | BMW  | 2018-08-30 10:00:44 | null
3  | Saab | 2018-08-30 22:00:44 | null

info:
id | body | date
1  | aaa  | 2018-08-30 08:10:10
2  | bbb  | 2018-08-30 22:00:44
3  | ccc  | 2018-08-30 10:00:44
```

And I would like to set *info_id* in *car* table by *date* from table *info*, so I would like to receive:

```
car:
id | name | date                | info_id
1  | Audi | 2018-08-30 08:10:10 | 1
2  | BMW  | 2018-08-30 10:00:44 | 3
3  | Saab | 2018-08-30 22:00:44 | 2
```

I would also like to preview these combined data in a format:

```
car_id | info_id | date
1      | 1       | 2018-08-30 08:10:10
2      | 3       | 2018-08-30 10:00:44
3      | 2       | 2018-08-30 22:00:44
```

Comment: I don't understand your expected output.  What is the source of the `info_id` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can join two tables

```
   select c.car_id,i.id,i.date 
   from car c inner join info i on c.date=i.date
```

As you change your question and want to update so below will work for you

```
UPDATE car a
JOIN info i
   on c.date=i.date
SET c.info_id = i.id
```

Comment: Thanks, this is good, but how can I update info_id by UPDATE?